# Как вывести названия всех файлов, а не кол-во которое загружаю <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

Как вывести названия всех загружаемых файлов, а не их количество (Показывает название файла, если загружаешь 1 файл)
А так же есть ли возможность управлять этими файлами, то что я буду точно загружать оставить, то что передумал убрать оттуда, не нажимая  заново?

```
<form role="form"  method="post" action="../fileServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-left: 370px">
              <input type="submit" class="button" value="Edit">
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форма с полем файла:

```html
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="input" name="files[]" accept="image" />
```

Обратите внимание на name="files[]"

В элементе input с типом file содержится невидимый атрибут files, при обращении к которому мы получаем объект FilleList, если input не пустой, иначе undefined.

```js
var inputFile = document.getElementById('input').files;
// вернет объект
FileList : {
    0,
    1,
    2,
    length: 3,
    item
}
```

В переменной file будет содержаться объект файла:

```js
File : {
    constructor: File {...},
    fileName: 'image.png',      // имя файла
    fileSize: 879394,              // размер файла
    name: 'image.png',          // имя файла
    size: 879394,                  // размер файла
    type: 'image/png',           // MIME тип файла
    getAsBinary,
    getAsDataURL,
    getAsText,
    lastModifiedDate: 'Thu May 26 2001 21:34:48 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time)'
}
```

Соответственно нужно работать с FileList, чтобы узнать количесто, имена файлов, или удалить файл.